# How to change the mouse cursor in java?

Tags: java, swing, mouse-cursor

I have a list of words inside the JList. Every time I point the mouse cursor at a word, I want the cursor to change into a hand cursor. Now my problem is how to do that?

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use a [MouseMotionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) on your JList to detect when the mouse enters it and then call `setCursor` to convert it into a `HAND_CURSOR`.

Sample code:

```
final JList list = new JList(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
list.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        final int x = e.getX();
        final int y = e.getY();
        // only display a hand if the cursor is over the items
        final Rectangle cellBounds = list.getCellBounds(0, list.getModel().getSize() - 1);
        if (cellBounds != null && cellBounds.contains(x, y)) {
            list.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        } else {
            list.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: what if I want the changes of the cursor to be happen when I point to the word, not in the list? Is it possible?

Comment: @Mikel I have updated my answer to display a hand only if the cursor is over the items in the list.

Comment: Yeah it works but there is a little bit problem. When I point the mouse beside the word, still it appears a hand cursor. I want the word only to appear a hand cursor when I point the mouse cursor.

Comment: you could use `Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)` and `Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR)` instead of `new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)` and `new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR)` to avoid recreating the cursors every time the mouse moves.

Comment: Came here for JavaFX. You want to set cursor on Scene like this. `imageScene.setCursor(javafx.scene.Cursor.CROSSHAIR);`

Answer (score 20):

You probably want to look at the [`Component.setCursor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor%28java.awt.Cursor%29) method, and use it together with the [`Cursor.HAND`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#HAND_CURSOR) constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `MouseListener` to the jList (or any ui component). Then implement the methods that `mouseEntered`, `mouseExited`

```
jList.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        cw.list.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        cw.list.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                    }
                });
```