# Customizing mouse cursor in Jfreechart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

Is it possible to change to cursor in JFreechart from the normal cursor into hand cursor,

together with a ball run across the chart like the chart in this link :

http://cafef.vn/Thi-truong-niem-yet/Bieu-do-ky-thuat/EPS-HNX-2.chn

I have no idea how it could be done in Jfreechart?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615940/changing-the-mouse-pointer-in-jtextpane and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359189/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-in-java

Comment: Are you this [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1173652/nguyen-hoai-thanh)?

Answer (score 2):

Just add your chart to a `ChartPanel` and call `addMouseMotionListener()`. For the listener, use a `MouseAdapter` that sets the cursor how your want it in `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()`. Here's the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).