# How to create custom cursor images in java

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating an application and based on the button the user clicks I want the cursor image to change. I have little to no clue how the toolkit works but after browsing a lot of people recommended that.

A major problem I am having with the toolkit is that I dont know how to add my custom images to it and I also do not know how to add a Point object to it... I tried MouseInfo.getPointerInfo() but that still will not work, neither will "new Point(0,0)" 
I am extending JPanel in this class already so I don't know if it is possible to extend Point at the same time...

Comment: have you tried anything? is there any coding **problem** in some specific code? please show [mcve]

Comment: First result of a quick google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359189/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-in-java

Comment: Itamar, no specific problem I am just confused
Thomas, I read through that link, that person is providing the built in cursor options java has provided, I want something custom made like a circle or a rectangle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I dont know how to add my custom images to it and I also do not know how to add a Point object to it

First of all you create a custom image that is 16x16

The the basic code is:

```
Image customimage = ...;
Cursor customCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(customImage, new Point(0, 0), "customCursor");
```

Then when you want to use it you do:

```
component.setCursor( customCursor );
```

To reset the cursor you use

```
component.setCursor( null );
```

Comment: When you mean Image customimage where should I store this png file?
In the same package as the rest of my classes?

Comment: Another thing is, new Point(0,0) was not working out for me because I have a point class already, but that shouldn't make a difference because if I make a separate constructor in my point class so it takes in 2 integer arguments, it still will not work. Error: The method createCustomCursor(java.awt.Image, java.awt.Point, java.lang.String) in the type Toolkit 
is not applicable for the arguments (java.awt.Image, mypackage.paint.Point, java.lang.String)

Comment: *"Another thing is, new Point(0,0) was not working out for me because I have a point class already"* Either fully qualify every reference to it, or (more likely) give it a better, or more specific name. To think of one, concentrate on the aspects of your point that are different to, or do more than, a `java.awt.Point` - base the name on those. E.G. `MapPoint` or `CharacterLocation` or..

Comment: I literally cannot set my image equal to a variable in the class, what is the command/method? getImage does not seem to be working...

Comment: @Wallace, you can use `ImageIO` to read an image file and yes is should be in the same package as the rest of your class files.